# What is JVM Bind?

Tags: jvm, jms, hornetq

I tried to run example from HornetQ and I got this error:

```
 [java] HornetQServer_0 out:  Deployment "JNDIServer" is in error due to: java.rmi.server.ExportException: Port already in use: 1098
```

Actually this is not the first time I got this kind of error. I can verify that port 1098 is indeed already in use (using Netstat command) but I just don't know which service using it. Is anybody has encountered such problem?

Thanks in advance for any response and help. :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Could be [JBOSS](http://community.jboss.org/thread/120633) or [Remote Admin Tool](http://www.sans.org/security-resources/idfaq/oddports.php).  Or [something else](http://www.digitalprank.org/how-to-solve-address-or-port-already-in-use-error-in-java/) like Outlook or Firefox.

Comment: That link is really helpful. But I just wonder if I can make the RAT from stop running. It's a part of basic service right?

Comment: I don't know.  Are you sure that's the app that's holding onto 1098?

Comment: I'm pretty sure Jboss is not using the port because I didn't start it. So according to you, it should be RAT right? I don't know if there's another process using that. From the shell I can see the PID of the service that using port 1098 is PID 5556 but I can find it in the task manager.